# Unable to access jarfile on server using VNC

Tags: java, jar, vnc

I'm trying to run a java application on a server computer by using VNC (tightVNC).

I have the java application in eclipse and it runs perfectly. Then I export it to a runnable jar file and upload the runnable jar file to the server. Now I'm trying to run the application (called ABUN_0.0.0.jar) using VNC.

I use `/u01/gatc/java/jdk1.6.0_10/bin/java -jar ABUN_0.0.0.jar&` (I've used this for previous versions of the app and its worked perfectly). However now I get `Unable to access jarfile ABUN_0.0.0.jar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
/u01/gatc/java/jdk1.6.0_10/bin/java -jar ABUN_0.0.0.jar&
```

use this,

```
/u01/gatc/java/jdk1.6.0_10/bin/java -jar /**path to jar**/ABUN_0.0.0.jar &
```

or

if Linux System,

check **ABUN_0.0.0.jar**'s **permission** level.

To give Permission,

```
chmod 755 /**path to jar**/ABUN_0.0.0.jar
```